# Attempting to use an Excel file as source for inventory using Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, networking

The Excel file is exported from the monitoring systems.

Excel sample data:

```
Caption IP Address  Machine Type    SiteCode2
NAS1-Home   192.168.18.10   linux   Home
NAS2-Home   192.168.18.11   linux   Home
NAS3-Home   192.168.18.10   linux   Home
SLO2-ASA-PROD-fw    10.10.100.93    Cisco ASA-5585 SC   SLO
SLO2-ASA-PROD-stby-FW   10.10.100.94    Cisco ASA-5585 SC   SLO
```

1 - Read the file and specific columns:

```
File = "Test.xlsx"
FWs = pd.read_excel(File, skiprows=2, usecols=['Device Name', 'IP Address', 'Machine Type', 'SiteCode2'])

###Dropping null value columns to avoid errors 
FWs.dropna(inplace = True)
```

2a - Execute some filtering:

```
Prod = FWs['Device Name'].str.contains('Prod|PROD|PRD|prd') & FWs['SiteCode2'].str.contains('CHI')
print (FWs[Prod], "\n")
```

2b - Results from query

```
                  Caption    IP Address       Machine Type SiteCode2
95       SLO2-ASA-PROD-fw  10.10.100.93  Cisco ASA-5585 SC       SLO
96  SLO2-ASA-PROD-stby-FW  10.10.100.94  Cisco ASA-5585 SC       SLO
```

3a - Test for values after the query in "IP Address":

```
for device in (FWs[Prod]['IP Address']):
print (device)
```

3b - Print query results in "IP address"

```
10.10.100.93
10.10.100.94
```

Works fine

4a -  Test for values in "Device Name"

```
for device in (FWs[Prod]['Device Name']):
print (device)
```

4b - Print query results in "Device Name"

```
SLO2-ASA-PROD-fw
SLO2-ASA-PROD-stby-FW
```

Works fine

Next step is where it fails

4 - Pass all query values per row, it fails:

```
for device in FWs[Prod].splitlines():
    fields = device.split()
    name = fields[0]
    ip = fields[1]
    type = fields[2]
    site = fields[3]
    print (name)
```

Error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2646, in get_loc
```

I am looking for a way to once filtering the rows is completed, extract the values to ssh and execute some code. Not sure the approach is correct, suggestions anyone?

Comment: Some sample input/output in a [mre] format would be helpful, as well as the full Traceback.

Comment: I would use `iterrows` or `itertuples` `for index, row in df.iter...` then you can deal with each value at a row level if you need to do row by row execution methods. might take a while though!

Comment: I added some input/output data. Thanks @r.ook

Comment: I was looking into iterrows, could not figure it out, will look into it again, or those other options mentioned. Thanks @Datanovice

Comment: You still don't have the full trace back, so it's hard to know what's your exact issue.  I wouldn't use `iterrows` though, you can just extract the filtered results to a `list/dict` for further processing.  It depends what you are trying to do after.  From your sample the `Prod` mask doesn't even work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [pandas.iterrows()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) you can do the trick:

```
for index, device in FWs[Prod].iterrows():
    name= device['Device Name']
    ip = device['IP Address']
    type_ = device['Machine Type']
    site = device['SiteCode2']
    print (name)
```

Attention: `type` is a reserved word in python use something else when reading `Machine Type`. I used `type_`